# Custom log message in GeoServer through POST request

Tags: geoserver

I'm trying to send a string message from my JavaScript client, to GeoServer, and have it show up in the GeoServer logs.

How might I do this?

I turned on 'Verbose' logging, and set the number of characters to log for incoming post requests to 1024, from the global settings page. However, I don't see the message showing up in the log.

My goal is to build a performance testing script, which parses the GeoServer log file, and compares render speed, among other things, for various data configurations. 
Here is a code snippet, JavaScript and OpenLayers 5:

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
  d = new Date();
  beginTime = d.getTime();
});

map.on("rendercomplete", function(e){
   if(beginTime > oldBeginTime){
     oldBeginTime = beginTime;
     d = new Date();
     finishTime = d.getTime();
     var elapsedTime = finishTime - beginTime;
     var postData = "Time: " + elapsedTime + " ms"; 
     var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     var url = "localhost:8080/geoserver/www/home.html";
     xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
     xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
     xhttp.send(postData);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors from Javascript? Or tried sending the POST from the command line using `curl`?

Comment: No errors on the JS side. Geoserver log says "Could not find layer group named www." Using curl, I get back a 404 not found. I've tried some other urls as well, localhost:8080/geoserver, localhost:8080, localhost:8080/geoserver/web... and others. Even using curl to make a correct rest api command, like adding a workspace, works just fine, but I don't see the post request string in the log, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: what code do you have in home.html that would add your message to the log file?

Comment: Do you see full POST parameters in the logs for other requests? Are requests logged before they get handled by the URL endpoint?

Comment: I do'nt have any code in the html file that would add a message to the log file. That is just the URL to the page that is being served where the JS is running. I assume all of that code happens GeoServer side, unless there is something there that I am missing.

Comment: The only full POST parameters that I see showing up in the logs are for getMap requests. I have 'Verbose Logging' turned on on GeoServer.